# Openfire on Mac OS X: can't log in after setup

Tags: macos, mac, jabber, xmpp

I'm trying to set up Openfire (http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) on Mac OS X. The install goes well, and I can start the server and enter the admin console via its System Preferences pane.

I run the setup, including specifying the password for the admin user. However, when I try to log into the admin console, I get the message "Login failed: make sure your username and password are correct and that you're an admin or moderator."

What gives? I've tried to RTFM, but the documentation seems to be really sketchy. Nowhere is the setup process mentioned in the install docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. On a lark I tried restarting the server after setup. After it restarted I was able to log in.